# Не выводит данные в html таблицу из json

Tags: javascript, html, json

У меня есть 3 значения в файле: дата, название филиала и сумма:

```
"values":[  
            {  
               "x":"02 (26.03.19-01.04.19)",
               "y":"МОСКВА",
               "value":119328.59
            },
```

Получилось вывести филиал и сумму, а вот по датам не получилось, как можно это исправить?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'filial.json',
    success: function(json) {
      var someData = [];


      for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
        // console.log(json.data[i].x);
        if (json.data[i]['graphId'] == 10) {
          for (j = 0; j < json.data[i]['values'].length; j++) {
            var name = json.data[i]['values'][j]['y'];
            var period = json.data[i]['values'][j]['x'];
            var found = false;
            var zz;
            for (var z = 0; z < someData.length; z++) {
              if (someData[z].label == name) {
                found = true;
                zz = z;
                break;
              }
            }
            if (!found) {
              someData.push({
                label: name,
                data: []
              });
              zz = someData.length - 1;
            }
            someData[zz].data.push(json.data[i]['values'][j]['value']);
            // if (typeof someData[name] == 'undefined') {
            //     someData[name] = [];
            // }
            // someData[name].push(json.data[i]['values'][j]['value']);
          }
        }
      }

      var html = '<table class="tab"><tr><th>Cборы за 2019 г.</th></tr>';
      for (var i = 0; i < someData.length; i++) {
        html += '<tr><td>' + someData[i].label + '</td>';
        for (var j = 0; j < someData[i].data.length; j++) {
          html += '<td>' + someData[i].data[j] + '</td>';
        }

        html += '</tr>';
      }
      html += '</table>';

      $('#table').append(html);

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, то обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас не сказано, какой должна быть таблица. Я предположил, что первый столбец - место, второй - период, третий - сумма. Результат ниже.

Один важный момент по Вашему коду: избегайте наращивать строковые данные и другие immutable типы путем добавления - это долго и дорого! Каждый раз берется исходная строка, копируется в новое место и к ней добавляется довесок. Используйте массив, а когда закончили добавление элементов, делайте `stringArray.join('')`. Я заменил Вашу переменную `html` на массив `htmlLines`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'filial.json',
    success: function(json) {
      var someData = [];


      for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
        // console.log(json.data[i].x);
        if (json.data[i]['graphId'] == 10) {
          for (j = 0; j < json.data[i].values.length; j++) {
            var record = json.data[i].values[j];
            var name = record.y;
            var period = record.x;
            var value = record.value;
            var found = false;
            var zz;
            for (var z = 0; z < someData.length; z++) {
              if (someData[z].label == name) {
                found = true;
                zz = z;
                break;
              }
            }
            if (!found) {
              someData.push({
                label: name,
                data: [],
                periods: [],
              });
              zz = someData.length - 1;
            }
            someData[zz].data.push(value);
            someData[zz].periods.push(period);
            // if (typeof someData[name] == 'undefined') {
            //     someData[name] = [];
            // }
            // someData[name].push(json.data[i]['values'][j]['value']);
          }
        }
      }

      var htmlLines = [];
      htmlLines.push('<table class="tab">')
      htmlLines.push('<tr><th colspan="3">Cборы за 2019 г.</th></tr>');
      htmlLines.push('<tr><th>Место</th><th>Период</th><th>Сумма</th></tr>');
      for (var i = 0; i < someData.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < someData[i].data.length; j++) {
          htmlLines.push('<tr>');
          if (j===0) {
            htmlLines.push('<td rowspan="' + someData[i].data.length + '">' + someData[i].label + '</td>');
          }
          htmlLines.push('<td>' + someData[i].periods[j] + '</td>');
          htmlLines.push('<td>' + someData[i].data[j] + '</td>');
        }

        htmlLines.push('</tr>');
      }
      htmlLines.push('</table>');

      $('#table').append(htmlLines.join('\n'));

    }
  });
});
```